# Collection type migration from sf2.8 to sf3

Tags: symfony-forms, symfony

Let's take into account this example: I've got a form type where I embed another type in a "collection fashion" as follows

```
->add('foo', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type'     => new FooType(),
    'error_bubbling' => false,
    'allow_add'      => true,
    'allow_delete'   => true,
    'required'       => false,
    'label'          => ' ',
    'entry_options'  => [
        'bar' => $options['bar'],
    ],
    'by_reference' => false,
])
```

and all works fine (I can add and remove elements easily).

Since I'm upgrading the framework from 2.8 to 3.0, I've read changelog and noticed

> The option type of the CollectionType has been removed in favor of the
>   entry_type option. The value for the entry_type option must be the
>   fully-qualified class name (FQCN).

So I've changed my form to

```
->add('foo', CollectionType::class, [
    'entry_type'     => FooType::class,
    'error_bubbling' => false,
    'allow_add'      => true,
    'allow_delete'   => true,
    'required'       => false,
    'label'          => ' ',
    'entry_options'  => [
        'bar' => $options['bar'],
    ],
    'by_reference' => false,
])
```

but when I add elements to collection, it seems that `ModelData` are collapsed into the same element (the last one of the collection).

So, imagine that I post entities with ids `[1,2,3]`, `ViewData` is correct whereas `ModelData` has an array collection with three elements: three foo(s) with id 3, so the same foo.

Does anyone understand what's going on here?

## Edit

This is `FooType` meaningful code

```
$resolver->setDefaults([
    'data_class' => 'Vendor\Bundle\Entity\Foo',
    'empty_data' => new Foo(),
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a symfony bug (unconfirmed; [read more](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/19165#issuecomment-228321945)) or a misuse of combination of FQCN in `entry_type` and `new` on `empty_data` of embedded form.

I'll update my answer properly when and if SF core team reply me in the issue.